# CSS gradient text will, on some browser sizes, duplicate the text at the end of the line

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, gradient, screen-resolution

I am building the header for a wordpress theme. We are using a gradient for text using CSS.

```css
body p.site-description,
body h1.site-title,
body h1.site-title a {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #DFBB4A, #C889AA, #A3004D);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #DFBB4A, #C889AA, #A3004D);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #DFBB4A, #C889AA, #A3004D);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #DFBB4A, #C889AA, #A3004D);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #DFBB4A, #C889AA, #A3004D);
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="site_info col-lg-4">
  <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#" rel="home">AKA Lily With Some Extra Text</a></h1>
  <p class="site-description">Just another WordPress site but it has a longer name than a wordpress site tagline would normally be</p>
</div>
```

It looks great for the most part.

[Screen at 840px wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMEEU.png)

However, on some screen sizes, such as 839px wide, some text at the end of the line (before text wrap) gets repeated at the beginning of the line. The text does not get added to the DOM or anything. The browser seems to be getting the positioning of the  and the  slightly wrong.

[Screen at 839px wide - THIS IS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/547A1.png)

This happens on the latest versions of Chrome and Opera, but not on Firefox. Ignoring IE for now.

This only happens to the h1/a tag, NOT the p tag.

The h1/a tag and the p tag have the same margin and padding - 0px.

Lastly, this is the result of me removing the h1 style:
[Screen at 839px wide with h1 style removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lDmG.png)
So it seems the a tag wrapped the text, while the h1 tag did not, so it appears in both places.

Has anybody happened upon this error before? How can I get around this? Thank you all in advance.